# Seed method isn't triggered on published IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, iis, entity-framework-migrations

I just published my app to IIS server (localhost).

This is to check the publish process. Everything went well, files copied, site started nicely, no error, database is created.

I miss one thing: Data. My seed method wasn't triggered and thus the initial data is missing.

I tried looking in Microsoft site, and also in StackOverflow, to no avail.

These are my migration config and seed:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : 
    DbMigrationsConfiguration<CobwebsCommon.DAL.CobwebsContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        ContextKey = "CobwebsCommon.DAL.CobwebsContext";
    }

    protected override void Seed(CobwebsCommon.DAL.CobwebsContext context)
    {
        //if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached == false)
        //    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
        Logger.Info("Cobwebs DB seed started");
        try
        {
            var db = new CobwebsContext();

            DbGen dbGen = new DbGen(context);
            dbGen.GenerateDb();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.Error("Error creating db: {0}", e);
        }
        Logger.Info("Cobwebs DB seed finished");

    }
}
```

Comment: _"My seed method wasn't triggered"_ - are you sure? Does your logging _work_?

Comment: Are you saving it? Why do you need `var db = new CobwebsContext();`

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes, My log file does have some rows, but none of the three in the code above

Comment: @BikalBhattarai It's how one of our developers wrote the dbGen class, it receives a context object, saveChanges is called inside of it

Comment: When running on visual studio it does work as expected

Comment: Where/how are you setting the initialiser?

Comment: @Chiptus See if you have `DbDatabase.SetInitializer` called from somewhere.

Comment: @BikalBhattarai It could also be in the `web.config`

Comment: @DavidG Oh sorry didn't see your comment... and yes indeed!

Comment: It's code first migrations, I don't have an initializer. Should I have one? If so, why does it work when running from vs?

Comment: The initializer drives database creation and seeding: http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/28/database-initializer-and-migrations-seed-methods/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so as you told me I should use an initializer. Not like on development, when deploying, web.config has to have an initializer (well, unless you don't need any db init data).

When you publish using the publish dialog in VS 2013, you have the option to tell that the DB is using Code First Migrations.
By this guide: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis, an initializer from type MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion should be added to web.config, but in my case it didn't and that's why the seed method wasn't triggered.

That problem with my project was that web.config already had a context tag, so i guess the publish sequence skipped adding its own initializer because it believed I know what I'm doing, which I don't :)

Deleting the relevant context tag fixed this. now the seed method is called, and logged into the logger.

Thank to all for your help